# In Rails models, can I change belongs_to to has_one and has_one to belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

If I have two models. Model1 belongs_to Model2, and Model2 has_one Model1. Thus I can access Model2 from Model1 as well as Model1 from Model2. Now my question is, can I change the relationship to **Model2 belongs_to Model1 and Model1 has_one Model2**? It also can let me traverse from Model1 to Model2 and from Model2 to Model1. I'm not sure of that, anyone can explain it please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly change a relationship from one way round to the other.

You'll obviously need to add a `model_1_id` column on the `model_two` table, migrate any existing associations across and remove the `model_2_id` column on the `model_one` table.

I can't think of anything else you'd particularly need to do to get it to work. The associations behave pretty much identically when `belongs_to` is paired with `has_one`.